# multiple commands in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, kubernetes, apt-key

I have just come across an article describing process of installing containerD runtime and I'm a little dubious about the command mentioned, maybe a typo but I want to get clarity on it. The command is as follows

```
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.lis
```

Now as far as I know the apt-key add - is used to add the key and the contents are read from the piped standard output for which - is there but what about the echo after it, if this is a separate command shouldn't it be separated by || or a semicolon ;? I know the command is fetching key from the repo and then updating the apt sources list but I'm confused about the syntax of the command.

Comment: Could you point to where you got this from? I think it's a matter of unfortunate formatting.  There should probably be a newline between the `-` and the `echo` in `-echo`. What I _believe_ you are looking at are two _separate_ pipelines.

Comment: @Kusalananda can you please elaborate "two separate pipelines" does having a space means it is a separate command? I have only heard of 3 ways to execute multiple Linux commands in a single line via ||, ; and &&. here's the article though https://thenewstack.io/deploy-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-ubuntu-server-using-containerd/

Comment: @JayD Kusalananda's point is that that's supposed to be two lines, not one. `curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -` on one line and `echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.lis` on the other.

Comment: @JayD Newline, not space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a typo. The correct commands are:

```
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | 
   sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | 
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

The first command downloads a gpg signature from `https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg` which is then piped to `sudo apt-key add -` (the `-` means "read from standard input") which adds the key to the list of known apt keys.

Then, the second command prints out the line describing the relevant repository and this is piped to `sudo tee` as a way of writing to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list`.

Taken together, the two commands add a new, signed repository to your system.